# Promise chain is not executed in nodejs

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I have the following code:

```
Q.fcall(->
    response = req.post({url:url, formData: formData})
    return response
  ).then((response) ->
    reply(response)
  )
```

It makes a request and when the server response execute the `reply` function, until here everything works fine. The response is in XML format:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<foxydata>
    <store_version>2.0</store_version>
    <result>SUCCESS</result>
    <messages>
        <message>Transaction Found</message>
    </messages>
    <transaction>
...
...
...
```

I want to use a node module([xml2js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xml2js)) to convert it. So I done this:

```
add = (request, reply) ->

  Q.fcall(->
    response = req.post({url:url, formData: formData})
    return response
  ).then((response) ->
    parseXML(response, (err, result) ->
      reply(result)
    ) 
  )
```

But in that case the reply is executed immidiately and the result is Empty. Any idea what I am missing/doing wrong?

Comment: If reply is being called by parseXML, you should show us the code for that function

Comment: @RobertLevy reply is a function that comes from the framework and is passed to my function, parseXML is coming from xml2js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Q.denodeify.

```
return Q.denodeify(parseXML)(response);
```

You must return the resulting promise to the then handler function for the result to be forwarded to the promise returned by then.

Answer (score 0):

Acutally, When you are creating promises, it has to be either resolved or rejected. So a promise function would take resolve, reject callbacks.

```
dothis
  .then(dothat, error)
  .then(dothattoo)
  .catch(error)

dothis = do(params);

do = function(params) {
  return PROMISE(function(resolve, reject) {
    // use params here as variables
    // do something with params
    if(params) {
      resolve(response)
    } else {
      reject("some error")
    }
  };
}

error = function(err) {
  // handle that err
}
```

In your case, do not return the response object, but pass it to next chain by resolving it.

Comment: Your answer is not really helpful, I dont want to use `PROMISE`, I have to use the Q library, and the `response` is an XML how can I resolve it.